# WinSCP script works fine manually, but failes when executed by SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, winscp, sql-server-agent

I have a WinSCP script that SFTPs a file from a remote server to a local directory. The script works fine when I execute it from the command line, but when I try to execute it as a command step in a SQL Server Agent job, the job fails. All the history tells me is:

```
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. The step did not generate any output. Process Exit Code 1. The step failed.
```

which could mean anything. I've tried to break the problem down to its core by stripping everything out of the script except an exit statement. It still fails, so I know the issue is not in the script. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Posting in case anyone else runs into this problem. The WinSCP FAQ [has a little section](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_scheduler) on these kinds of problems, but missed one ridiculously simple possibility: does the job have access to the script being executed?

Regardless of who created the script, the command will be executed by the SQLSERVERAGENT account. If you're like me, you keep your scripts under your user account's home directory, which SQLSERVERAGENT *doesn't have access to*. Move the script to a directory it can read and see if that fixes it for you. I used the Users\Public directory.